# Proof of Completeness Theorem in Enderton's Logic, satisfiability of $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm reading the proof of the Completeness Theorem from Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic". I'm having issues seeing how the following highlighted sentence actually holds (excerpt from page 137).

> Let $\Lambda$ be the set of logical axioms for the expanded language. Since $\Gamma \cup \Theta$ is consistent, there is no formula $\beta$ such that $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$ tautologically implies both $\beta$ and $\neg \beta$. (This is by Theorem 24B; the compactness theorem of sentential logic is used here.) **Hence there is a truth assignment $v$ for the set of all prime formulas that satisfies $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$.**

I have tried to reason "by contrapositive". That is, suppose a set of (sentential) formulas $\Sigma$ is unsatisfiable. Then, vacuously, every truth assignment that satisfies $\Sigma$ will also satisfy any formula at all. Hence $\Sigma$ tautologically implies any formula. In particular, for any given formula $\beta$, $\Sigma$ tautologically implies both $\beta$ and $\neg\beta$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks right to me. Remember it well, cause "consistent implies satisfiable" is used just as often, if not more than "valid implies provable".