# Proof of Completeness Theorem in Enderton's Logic, satisfiability of Γ∪Θ∪Λ

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I have similar question with this post [Proof of Completeness Theorem in Enderton's Logic, satisfiability of Γ∪Θ∪Λ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165335/proof-of-completeness-theorem-in-endertons-logic-satisfiability-of-gamma-cu), so I quote some of his/her description:

> I'm reading the proof of the Completeness Theorem from Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic". I'm having issues seeing how the following highlighted sentence actually holds (excerpt from page 137).

> > Let $\Lambda$ be the set of logical axioms for the expanded language. Since $\Gamma \cup \Theta$ is consistent, there is no formula $\beta$ such that $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$ tautologically implies both $\beta$ and $\neg \beta$. (This is by Theorem 24B; the compactness theorem of sentential logic is used here.) **Hence there is a truth assignment $v$ for the set of all prime formulas that satisfies $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$.**

But **my wondering** is:

This proof is part of the proof which is going to prove "**Any consistent set ($\Gamma$) of formulas is satisfiable.(completeness theorem)**", but the preceding highlighted sentence in the quoted paragraph says :"
**there is a truth assignment $v$ that satisfies $\Gamma \cup \Theta \cup \Lambda$**", doesn't it mean **"the consistent set $\Gamma$  is satisfiable"**? If it does, doesn't we reach the conculsion directly?

Comment: That step is only a "propositional" consistency: there is a *truth assignment* to prime formulas. That does not imply the consistency of the formula from a "predicate logic" point of view. Consider the simple example $\lnot \forall x (x=x)$: from the propositional point of view it is simply $\lnot p$ that is obviously satisfiable by a truth assignment but it is not so as predicate logic formula.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is that I misinterpret the "satisfiable" in "Any consistent set (Γ) of formulas is satisfiable" as "tautologically satisfiable", which should be "logically satisfiable".